# Django Model auto modified date issue

Tags: django, django-models

I have a base model with these two fields among others -

```
last_synced = models.DateTimeField(null=True, editable=False)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

last_synced is null by default and modified date is updated everytime the model is updated. 
I have a get_syncable_models in my Model Manager which returns all rows, for which the modified date is greater than last_synced date

```
def get_syncable_models(self):
    return self.filter(
        Q(modified__gt=F('last_synced')) |
        Q(last_synced__isnull=True),
        reviewed=True,
    )
```

The get_syncable_models functions is called by a batch process and updates all the models with last_synced = timezone.now() .
However, while saving the modified date is greater than the last_synced date(because timezone.now() in the Django framework is called few milliseconds after timezone.now() is called in the application layer), so get_syncable_models function will effectively work only when last_synced is null.

I am thinking of two options here -

1. Write a save method and check if the last_synced has been changed and then add a second to the last_synced date. This also means that I have to modify all the subclasses where save functions have been called, given that this class is a superclass.
2. Add a "sync" flag in the model, which will be set to true by the batch job. Write a save method and check if the flag is true and then add a second to the last_synced date.

Would much appreciate if there is a cleaner Django solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is the time that an entry was synced important for you? Or are you using this data just to check if the entry is synced?

If the last question is true, I'd switch it to a boolean field `"is_synced"`. Using two columns to determine if something is in sync can be really expensive down the line if your DB grows.

Now, if you really want to keep that column as a date field because it's useful for you, another alternative would be checking if the difference between `modified` and `last_synced` is within a timeframe of, let's say, 1 minute.